# Merge multi-dimensional array preserving keys

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

So I have an array as follows. I want to merge all of these into one array of `key => value`.

**Input :**

```
$logTypes = array(
    'user_management'   => array(
        1001 => 'A new user was added',
        1002 => '#user_name# accessed user management',
        1003 => 'Created',
        1004 => 'Edited/Updated'),
    'report_management' => array(
        2001 => '#user_name# Added a new report',
        2002 => '#user_name# viewed "edit history" for the report #report_name#',
    ),
);
```

**Required Output :**

```
array (
  1001 => 'A new user was added',
  1002 => '#user_name# accessed user management',
  1003 => 'Created',
  1004 => 'Edited/Updated',
  2001 => '#user_name# Added a new report',
  2002 => '#user_name# viewed "edit history" for the report #report_name#',
)
```

I tried various permutations of `array_merge`, `array_map`, `array_values` but they just don't work as a whole, like some of them manage to merge but re-index the keys etc. etc.

**My attempts:**

`logTypes = call_user_func('array_merge', array_values(self::$logTypes));`

`$logTypes = call_user_func('array_push', self::$logTypes);`

`$logTypes = call_user_func_array('array_merge', self::$logTypes);`

`$logTypes = array_values(array_values(self::$logTypes));`

`$array = array_map('current', self::$logTypes);`

`$merged = array_merge(...self::$logTypes);`

Finally I had to resort to what I was trying to avoid all along, looping through each array :l

```
$plain_array = array();
foreach (self::$logTypes as $types) {
    $plain_array += $types;
}
```

It works, *so now my question is that, Is there any other way to achieve the desired result, using the above array_* functions ?*

**If I may add, may the shortest solution win!!** :)

Comment: You could try `array_replace` function ```$plain_array = array();
foreach ($logTypes as $types) {
    $plain_array = array_replace($plain_array, $types);
}```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I am looking for **not having to loop manually** through the original array.

Comment: Non loop solution ```array_reduce(
    $logTypes,
    function($carry, $types) {
        $carry = array_replace($carry, $types);
        return $carry;
    },
    []
);```

Comment: Thanks @FallDi your solution does work, I even shortened it `array_reduce(self::$logTypes, function($carry, $types) {
            return $carry += $types;
        }, [])`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
array_reduce($logTypes, function($carry, $item) {
    return $carry + $item;
}, []);
```

output:

```
array (
  1001 => 'A new user was added',
  1002 => '#user_name# accessed user management',
  1003 => 'Created',
  1004 => 'Edited/Updated',
  2001 => '#user_name# Added a new report',
  2002 => '#user_name# viewed "edit history" for the report #report_name#',
)
```

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$new_array = $logTypes['user_management'] + $logTypes['report_management'];
```

[PHP doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

> If you want to append array elements from the second array to the first array while not overwriting the elements from the first array and not re-indexing, use the + array union operator

Comment: My Dear :) , The Input array isn't just limited to those two keys, I just shortened it to keep the question succinct. Thanks.